# How to call data from database based on user who login and display in form column/field in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i want to display the username based on user that login to the application and put it inside field form (username)

this is code for my form
       `<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])?>`

this is code for calling the username based on the login user

```
<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->username ?>
```

but i dont know how to put the username inside the textinput

Comment: $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'value'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->username])

Comment: @Sfili_81 thank you so much ! its worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a necessary value in the model object that passes to ActiveFrom widget:

```
<?= $model->username = Yii::$app->user->identity->username; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to load your model data in your controller.

In your TestController

```
public function actionTest(){
  $model = new User();
  $model->username = Yii::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->username;
  if($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()){
     $model->save();
     // and ...
  }

  return $this->render('view', ['model'=>$model]);
}
```

In your view file

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])?>
```

In this case if you want to prevent user from changing value of user name change your controller code to something like this:

```
public function actionTest(){
  $model = new User();
  $model->username = Yii::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->username;
  if($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()){
     // Overwrite user input.
     $model->username = Yii::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->username;
     $model->save();
     // and ...
  }     
  return $this->render('view', ['model'=>$model]);
}
```